# .NET Core - 404 error on server only

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis-10, razor-pages

I have a very simple .NET Core test application that runs on my development machine but causes a 404 when run on my server under IIS 10.  Initially, the goal was to return a few database records in JSON, like a web service. However, to narrow the field of search for the error, I have changed the application to return a single, constant string. The result is the same -- works on the dev machine and fails on the server.

On the dev machine, I ran it from Visual Studio 15.5.7. I published to the server using Web Deploy.

Based on other posts, I also tried setting "No Managed Code" for the IIS App Pool, but it made no difference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
namespace api.iVoterGuide.com.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/ballot")]
    public class BallotController: Controller {
        // GET api/value  --  ballot/542
        [HttpGet("{eleck}")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get(short elecK)
        {
            yield return "[ 1, 2, 3]";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace api.iVoterGuide.com
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace api.iVoterGuide.com
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
     <!-- It works either with or without this CORS code -->
     <system.webServer>
          <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
          <httpProtocol>
               <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
               </customHeaders>
          </httpProtocol>
      </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Release.pubxml (EDITED)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>e86ba648-3c13-472c-b91c-1d0925762870</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\PublishOutput</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57342/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "api.iVoterGuide.com": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "api/values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57343/"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Following the advice from another article (which I can no longer find) I tried running my app from the command line.

```
D:\wwwroot\api.iVoterGuide.com>dotnet .\api.ivoterguide.com.dll
Error: An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (api.ivoterguide.com.deps.json) was not found:
package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'
path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-linux-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-osx-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x86.xml
```

Here is the --info result on the server:

```
D:\wwwroot\api.iVoterGuide.com>dotnet --info
Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

Version  : 2.0.6
Build    : 74b1c703813c8910df5b96f304b0f2b78cdf194d
```

Even with this information I have not been able to solve the problem. I have tried installing the newest .NET version, changing the .NET Core version in my csproj (), and several other small changes suggested by other articles.

I still cannot get to run.  Any suggestions.

Comment: Microsoft has published step-by-step instructions in excruciating detail here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?tabs=aspnetcore2x Have you followed all of those steps?

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I read about dotnet publish, and since it is the approved way, I changed to use it. I will edit the pubxml above to my new one. Unfortunately, I still get a 404.  If you have other ideas, I would appreciate them.

Comment: Running from the command line has revealed additional information that  it is a missing assembly.  I have added the details to the end of the main post.  I still cannot get it to run.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to install .Net Core Windows Server Hosting on the server, [as described here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/publish-asp-net-core-2-0-application-on-iis/).  It can be [downloaded here](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting).

It was **not** necessary to set PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest to false in the .csproj file.

I can either publish from Visual Studio or using the command line (dotnet publish -c Release -o bin\PublishOutput). The latter is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your routing is not done.try with your **Url+/api/ballot**.

Example: https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/ballot.
Here **https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net** is your azure url and **api/ballot** is your launch url defined in launchSettings.json file like "launchUrl": "api/ballot/",

[Route("api/[controller]")] should be in your controller class.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your web.config file should contain something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
<add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule"
resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\{dll's} path.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I changed by web.config to look like yours, but I still get a 404.

Comment: Could you send a screenshot or more detailed error that you get?

Comment: Also you can get logs by adding logs folder in your published files folder and changing web.config stdoutLogEnabled="true". This will generate files in your logs folder, where you can get more detailed error description and even stack trace.

Comment: And also when creating IIS website, which physical path have you specified?

Comment: I have added the exact message when running it from the command line, revealing that it is a missing assembly. Is that as good as a screenshot? The physical path is D:\wwwroot\api.iVoterGuide.com.

Comment: I have a final suggestion, it seems to me this will help. Add this line to your web projects .csproj file, publish it again, more files will have to be generated I your publish folder after this step, the line to add is:               <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>                                                                             Add it at the end of <PropertyGroup> part.

Answer (score 0):

Check the bindings in your IIS site settings. One of the possible reasons is, if the IP address is specified in the bindings and it is used by another application